# C# lists .findall, find partial matches

Tags: c#, list

I am using lists in c# and I am trying to find a partial or full result in a string

```
 List<GoogleMusicSong> artistname = gplaying.FindAll(delegate(GoogleMusicSong er) { return er.Artist == Txt_Search.Text; });
```

So I want to find all matches of txt_serch.txt e.g if I search for tribe I want it to find results for "A Tribe Called Quest"

Thankd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
var artistName = 
    gplaying.FindAll(er => er.Artist.Contains(Txt_Search.Text));
```

Keep in mind that this will cause the search to be case sensitive. If you want to do the search in a case insensitive fashion, you'll have to use something like:

```
var artistName =
    gplaying.FindAll(er => er.Artist
        .IndexOf(Txt_Search.Text, 
            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > 0);
```